# PHP RegEx add space

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
John 1:9
```

and the following php code:

```
$parts = preg_split('/[^a-z]/i', $a,2);
var_dump($parts);
```

It returns the following result (as i expect)

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'John' (length=4)
  1 => string '1:9' (length=3)
```

However, i might want the book "1 John 1:9" and it doesn't work to detect "1 John". How do i need to change the regex code to accept numbers 1-4 and a space before the book name?

Comment: What do you mean by the book name? What's your input and expected output?

Comment: "John" is a book name from the Bible, but it can also be "1 John" which is another book name. Also there is for example "1 Corinthians". A book name from the Bible with a number before.

Comment: `preg_split('/([1-4])?\s?[a-zA-Z]', $a,2);` should sort you out :)      explaining: "It may have numbers from 1-to-4, it may have a space, and it has certainly letters from a-to-z, including capitals"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than just splitting then you'll need to write a regex to match each part.

You could use something like:

```
/^((?:[1-4] )?[a-z]+) ([\d:]*)$/
```

Then you'd use `preg_match` as follows:

```
preg_match('/^((?:[1-4] )?[a-z]+) ([\d:]*)$/', $string, $parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
preg_match('/^((?:\d{1,4} )?\S+) (.+)$/', $string, $matches);
```

The book name (with optional number) is in `$matches[1]` and the rest in `$matches[2]`

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to check if the first result is numeric and if so join the first two keys.

```
$parts = preg_split('/[^a-z]/i', $a);
if (is_numeric($parts[0])) {
    $parts[0] = array_shift($parts) . ' ' . $parts[0];
}
var_dump($parts);
```